# how to only return strings that end in ".php" using awk

Tags: awk, logs

So I am very very new to using awk, I am trying to find the results for entries that only end in ".php". I cannot seem to figure out how to only display those specific entries. Please help.

```
cat apache.log  | awk '{print $ 7} ' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr   

  4 /main/set.php
  4 /main/search.php
  4 /main/call.php
  4 /kernel/add.php
  4 /finance/get.php
  3 /system/request.php
  3 /system/list.php
  3 /printer/get.php
  3 /kernel/get.php
  3 /finance/search.php
  2 /system/remove.php
  1 /system/set.php?value=56107
  1 /system/set.php?value=48930
  1 /system/set.php?value=43706
  1 /system/set.php?value=40718
  1 /system/set.php?token=EuQWLAMegG
  1 /system/set.php?timeout=36122
  1 /system/set.php?session=syL_XvQzCc
  1 /system/set.php?secret=Edtm_UVCwy
  1 /system/set.php?name=APxewjhRBL
  1 /system/set.php?key=bxYETGihzL
  1 /system/set.php?aws=XYUERQbtu-
  1 /system/set.php?aws=oiyfEeWzYk
  1 /system/set.php?aws=dzTgcALKEV
```

Comment: Did you typo your command?  `awk '{print $ 7} '` shouldn't work.

Comment: `awk '/php$/{print}` like this?

Comment: @guillermochamorro: It seems like OP is only wanting to search for things in the 7th column

Comment: `awk '$7 ~ /php$/{print $7}`

Comment: Does `/system/set.php?value=56107` end in `.php`?

Comment: [edit] your question to provide the expected output. It's not at all clear what you mean by `entries that only end in ".php"`

Answer (score 0):

You can Try something like this if you want to search for entries in 7th column ending with php

```
awk '$7 ~ /\.php$/{print $7}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use grep to only display the ones ending in .php using quotes with a withespace like ".php ".

Inserted in your code (with the awk fixed) that looks like this:

```
cat apache.log  | awk '{print $7}' | grep ".php " | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```